# Maven Error: Could not find or load main class (pom.xml file)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I'm struggling to execute a jar file that I'm creating. This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject3</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>

   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject3.SSBStub</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

    <dependencies>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I try to run this jar file on command prompt, I get an error saying "Could not find or load main class". I've tried everything and can't seem to resolve it. Can someone please help me with this?

And also, can someone show me where I can find the manifest file too? I don't know where to look for it in netbeans.

Thanks

Comment: Does `SSBStub.class` exist in your jar file?

Comment: It should do. Its my main class. The way I created this jar file was by running the following goals on the pom.xml file "clean install". This created the jar file which I assume contains the class. I'm not sure how to check if the jar file contains the file

Comment: Post `jar -tf <your.jar>` log.

Comment: @lexicore, hmmm, when I try to run that command in the command prompt, I get a message saying jar is not recognizable as an internal or internal command

Comment: Is JDK correctly installed?

Comment: @lexicore yeah I've been running this project and its been working fine. It's just this bit that's giving me issues

Answer (score 1):

If your are trying to run it using the command prompt you would want all dependencies to be present in your jar itself.

You can use the maven-assembly-plugin for this. Use the below code to achieve this.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.mavenproject3.SSBStub</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                <phase>package</phase> 
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Run with maven goals  : **mvn clean package**

This should create two jars in your target directory. One without the dependencies and one with all dependencies. Run the jar named: myJar-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: quick question, so I have one dependency, the name of that dependency is:wiremock-standalone. Is there a specific way of passing that between the descriptor refs tag?

Comment: Im also getting an error message that says the plugin tag is malformed. I added the code you've given me after the closing property tag

Comment: @Matt you should add this code instead of your jar-plugin as
<build><plugins>--given-code---</plugins></build>

Comment: @Matt ideally you would want to add all dependencies of your project to the jar file, why do you want to add it to descriptor refs?

Comment: Hi @Aman J, I've done that. I'm now getting the following error: "No main manifest attribute" in the jar file.

Comment: @Matt just missed a '<' in the code. sorry for this mistake. Corrected it. Try now.

Comment: Hi @Aman, Yep that error is gone... however, I've got other txt files in my project that I've referenced in my code, and as a result I'm getting an error which says "could not find xxx document". Do I need to somehow ensure those files are captured in the jar file? And if so, how?